# How do I add a image to a Freebase Topic ?

Tags: image, freebase

I am trying to add a image to my freebase topic, How can i do this ? I have heard that it is no longer possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're correct; this is no longer possible. See [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/freebase-discuss/alNEHISvpAA/ncyMIRUr_tQJ) by Brendan Neutra, one of the Freebase team at Google.